# crystal reports sap .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

if you please help me out i am trying to create a crystal report and the code behind the page goes as follows... when i run the application the web page is loading for hours with no result....

```
namespace WebApplication11

{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //      Below is the final code for reports.
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1(); // .xsd file name
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // Just set the name of data table
            dt.TableName = "db.Customer_Orders";
            dt = getAllOrders(); //This function is located below this function
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            // Your .rpt file path will be below
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("c:/users/dell/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication11/WebApplication11/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
            //set dataset to the report viewer.
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        }
        public DataTable getAllOrders()
        {
            //Connection string replcae 'databaseservername' with your db server name
            string sqlCon = "User ID=User-PC;PWD=; server=USER-PC/SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=SampleDB;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=FALSE;Connect Timeout=0";
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataSet ds = null;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            try
            {
                Con.Open();
                //Stored procedure calling. It is already in sample db.
                cmd.CommandText = "getAllOrders";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = Con;
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Users");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    Con.Close();
            }
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the stored procedure manually?  How long does that take in comparison?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the worker process to see where it's blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you appear to be missing a line after `CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;`:

`crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();`

But as Tung said- attach a breakpoint and step-through to see where it's getting stuck.